# Clarification about Boolean Algebra expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

I have been working on a boolean algebra problem. I have to simplify the following:$$\overline{A(\overline{C+D})}+BE$$

The only part I don't understand is how to deal with the double bar, and I can't find any examples of this from my lecture. Thank you.

Comment: Can you write $\overline{C+D}$ without the overline?

Answer (score 2):

The bar is the complementation operator.  (logical not).

When asked to "simplify", you are expected to use de Morgan's laws and such until the only negations are of literals.

$$\begin{align}\overline {~X~Y~} ~&=~ \overline X+\overline Y\\[1ex] \overline {~X + Y~} ~&=~ \overline X~\overline Y\end{align}$$

Recall also that in Boolean logic, double negation of an expression equals the expression itself.

$$\begin{align}\overline {~\overline X~} ~&=~ X\end{align}$$

---

So substituting $Z=C+D$, can you simplify $\overline{A\, \overline Z}+B\,E$ ?